# UITableViewCell detail click

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a problem. I have `UITableView` and customized `UITableViewCell` cell. My `UITableViewCell` has accessory view set to `Disclosure indicator`. I want after click show details and it works fine. But now I must do a small swipe with finger to right on `UITableViewCell`. When I am clicking, it does not work. I have delete row too and it works fine. Where can be the problem?

[My storyboard](http://postimg.org/image/lr13ishgp/)

Comment: Could you show your code for tableRow:didselectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Please show your code related to `UITableView`.

Comment: This is it http://pastebin.com/CxAEPN3k. I havent didselectRowAtIndexPath. It is a problem?

Comment: I found bug. I have UIGestureTap for dismiss keyboard.